# SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-mail

FYI, I'm following a tutorial on how to build a social media, the part where you set up an email server to send reset password messages to users. I understand that nowadays, Google has implemented policies that prevented applications from sending out emails unless they are deemed secure enough, so I try to work around this using an app password for custom app.

So far, I've already created an app password on my main google account. I've already set these following variables: MAIL_SERVER, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_USE_TLS, MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD in my terminal, with MAIL_PASSWORD set to my app password. I then opened the flask shell several times and tested things out, but all I got is this error message `SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first`
Here is the tutorial in question: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support

Comment: The error explain what you must do: call the function `connect` before transmitting data. Blogs are OK to get an idea, but you should not forget to look at official documentation.